# Scala, Specs2 and shared state

Tags: scala, testing, specs2

I am writing some *Specs2* specifications; that looks like:

```
class ComponentSpecification extends Specification with Mockito {

  private val dependency = mock[Dependency]
  private val subject = new Component(..)

  "methodOne" should {
    "handle happy path" in {
       val result = subject.methodOne("Param1", 42)
       result must ...
       there was one(dependency).something()
    }

    "deal with border case" in {
       val result = subject.methodOne("", -1)
       result must ...
       there was one(dependency).something()
    }
  }
}
```

However, those tests fails because the `mock[Dependency]` is shared.

- One solution would be to make them sequential and reset the mock before each test but this look odd and as written in the doc about *"Parallel by default"*:

> it encourages to write independent examples when the result of a given example should not be influenced by others

- Another would be to move the `val` to the test itself. But while I should be able to reduce the duplication with this still looks like a strange structure. And looks like the `subject` is stateful while it should not.
- I can also try to use a less strict approach by verifying with `there was atLestOne(dependency).something()` but:

  1. this does not validate that the method was called in this specific test case and
  2. argument capture and validation is painful.

So my question is:

How can I create readable tests with detailed verifications on mock.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to accept the answer from @Mario Galic. However, regarding the comment of @Eric (author of Specs2) I ended with a method that creates the context as expected but removes duplication. By using pattern matching I extract the interesting part :

```
class ComponentSpecification extends mutable.Specification with Mockito {
  def givenOneCallToMethodOneWithDependency(s:String, i:Int):(Result, Dependency) = {
    val dependency = mock[Dependency]
    val subject = new Component(dependency)
    val result = subject.methodOne(s, i)
    (result, dependency)
  }

  "methodOne" should {
    "handle happy path" in new FooScope {
      val (result, dependency) = givenOneCallToMethodOneWithDependency("Param1", 42)
      there was one(dependency).something()
    }

    "deal with border case" in new FooScope {
      val (result, dependency) = givenOneCallToMethodOneWithDependency("", -1)

      there was one(dependency).something()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Scopes](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.3.4/org.specs2.guide.Scopes.html) can provide fresh state to each test like so

```
class ComponentSpecification extends mutable.Specification with Mockito {
  trait FooScope extends Scope {
    val dependency = mock[Dependency]
    val subject = new Component(dependency)
  }

  "methodOne" should {
    "handle happy path" in new FooScope {
      val result = subject.methodOne("Param1", 42)
      there was one(dependency).something()
    }

    "deal with border case" in new FooScope {
      val result = subject.methodOne("", -1)
      there was one(dependency).something()
    }
  }
}
```

where there is no need to reset the mock before each test.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing an equivalent with a private method that returns a `Tuple[Subject, Dependency]` but this is cleaner. I also fall on the `isolated` keyword, do you have an argument against or in favor of that one https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.3.4/org.specs2.guide.Isolation.html over _scopes _?

Comment: I would avoid using `isolated` because I am not very confident with its implementation with mutable specs. It needs to do all sorts of contorsions to get there. Also note that `Scope` relies on the `DelayedInit` functionality which is not guaranteed to stay in Scala 3. So if you want to play it safe: `val dependency = mock[Dependency]; val subject = new Component (..)` in each example...